# Build union of keys in recursive object with specific shape

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to extract the `ACTION_` keys from the following config shape (it's a state machine). Notice that a state can have `initial`, `states`, then any number of actions:

```
export const config = {
  initial: 'STATE_1',
  states: {
    STATE_1: {
      ACTION_5: 'STATE_2',
      initial: 'STATE_3',
      states: {
        STATE_3: {
          ACTION_1: 'STATE_4',
          ACTION_2: 'STATE_2',
        },
        STATE_4: {
          ACTION_3: 'STATE_3',
        },
      },
    },

    STATE_2: {
      ACTION_4: 'STATE_1',
      ACTION_5: 'STATE_3',
      initial: 'STATE_5',
      states: {
        STATE_5: {
          ACTION_6: 'STATE_6',
        },
        STATE_6: {
          ACTION_6: 'STATE_5',
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

The best I can come up with at the moment is this:

```
type ActionUnion<T> = T extends { [K in keyof T]: infer U }
  ? U extends { states: any }
    ? ActionUnion<U['states']> // recursive call for nested states
    : U extends { [key: string]: any }
      ? keyof Omit<U, 'initial' | 'states'> // extract action keys
      : never
  : never;
```

But this is inferred as `"STATE_1" | "STATE_2"`.

```
type T1 = ActionUnion<typeof config>; // should be "ACTION_1" | "ACTION_2" | etc...
```

I think I'm probably making this more complex than it needs to be.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7ycgZgSwOZwC8cA3gFBxw7I4w4CGANgFxwDkAygCoCCXAogH0AjGwA0FOOnoxgqVuUqVufIcIWSlcHgGEuASQDyAOUEBWVp14DBAJnGal1WgxbsVNgMwOtlabPlSRy0PIU8NX19dAxMRS1DBABYfSKVoo1NbeOshewlUuABffNSExIiC7T0MwXD3HNqUyOLgopLKFscErKDI9Njy+tURJrTq2Ishr1HKZzombOGzGakYGTkKyITJxUr+0wA2RZsDlY723wSj3r3xw+OhZYutFuaL17ayQoBuMjIYACeYGAcA4a1kAFUaCgADxcAB8RDgXDgoFkyAAJqhSKt1oEAErAJBQDEw6hYYBQOAAaTEcHoyABiMKkgA-DS4AAfUHg4BQnCwrgAbTY-jkbAAukLqRL4ZJWMhgAA3Sm-f5AkE8BB0FD8wWI4gotHATHYkhwaVUZBwADWwABECwyIlrHJlLgEKKbI9qJA6KxOLFgQZAK9WnZWp1yD1yBhEJFQcliIA9Mm4FAiQBXKCoHAqxBMRhwLDQOCK9DADG4gKOVie42mnFCu0A1joKDUPAu+mMsO+dktx1wQwAW1ocbpbDmrjYXPYiZTabRUHo2vp2oF1pbqFaCuVlPlZf3UDVgOByIADEiwesYzCz8Ah5hcHh4d84Km4A-L0iAEQJYRfznf8GlsIDuRA4ZPHAuBIJsRIYLgx5EKuX91XPLhhCRSNNzvB8nxQF83w-NNv0wpFFRVKkAApUAACwgTNGCrAAjEFf32EREM4sC52AGAEAAOmEgBKMggA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilities:

`Prettify` - simplifies the type shown by the IDE:

```
type Prettify<T> = T extends infer R ? { [K in keyof R]: R[K] } : never;
```

Next, using the [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) we will map through the object and check if the key of it starts with `ACTION_` then we pick the key, otherwise if the property is an object, we recursively check in the same manner the keys of that property, if none of the previous conditions are true, we just assign `never`. Then we extract the values of that object to get the union of values:

```
type ActionUnion<T extends object> = Prettify<
  {
    [K in keyof T]: K extends `ACTION_${string}`
      ? K
      : T[K] extends object
      ? ActionUnion<T[K]>
      : never;
  }[keyof T]
>;
```

Usage:

```
// type Actions = "ACTION_4" | "ACTION_5" | "ACTION_6" | "ACTION_3" | "ACTION_1" | "ACTION_2"
type Actions = ActionUnion<typeof config>;
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7ycgZgSwOZwC8cA3gFBxw7I4w4CGANgFxwDkAygCoCCXAogH0AjGwA0FOOnoxgqVuUqVufIcIWSlcHgGEuASQDyAOUEBWVp14DBAJnGal1WgxbsVNgMwOtlabPlSRy0PIU8NX19dAxMRS1DBABYfSKVoo1NbeOshewlUuABffNSExIiC7T0MwXD3HNqUyOLgopLKFscErKDI9Njy+tURJrTq2Ishr1HKZzombOGzGakYGTkKyITJxUr+0wA2RZsDlY723wSj3r3xw+OhZYutFuaL17ayQoBuMjIYACeYGAcAAClBgDA6FgAQAeLgAPiIcC4cFAsmQABNUFRsMAoHAAEpwAD8pDgAG0ANK4uAAa2AAIgWCJAF1WITqayinBWMhgAA3fG-f5AkE8BB0FAAVRoKHhaJAGOxcAgACMAFbASVI4jgyHQuGSXaUam0hlMllcdlwGno4BYnEAA32ggAJCR0FBqHhCk7WmSqa1WFwuYrlTj1VrJQHtJKcDK5ch4VyEcG4PyhVBfh0KRbmSjWWQESKAPSluCA4FxqVoZEAIldiXrcAAPnBG3dzC3252Yocex3XZ5B32asJR67bPXRdWJbWccR5wnkLKV7Cq8AC5hcHgS2QgA)

Comment: I don't understand why it needs `as const`. For example, I can get the actions from a flat object like this: https://tsplay.dev/w6GyeN

Comment: Pardon me, I thought we are retrieving the values, not the keys. If we would actually take the value of the `config[ACTION_...]` we would get a `string`, not the exact value. Updating the answer

Comment: Anyway, the example that you are showing in the playground isn't relevant, since you are passing type directly, not a typeof config. You can see the relevant comparison [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA3gKBvAXDA5HAfQDc4AbXAGgxgCMdcbizc0BfNNUSWGpVauPUIlyVTHTyMRLVvAgwu0DmgD0KmFACeABwCmMAIJ90azGcExoAJwCWYAOYBuVerO0c1u05cx2WvYZ8-rogAGbwzj7BMABCxj5uVrpwACbgpJrYMABEwmTZzqaJyWlgGe45UvmF6n46+nHIwWG0jkA)